# Powershell modify output of a string

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I am trying to manipulate this string: `mbx74542cbb45d544c2bf269ae87a978be8:2` to end up looking like this string:
`74542cbb-45d5-44c2-bf26-9ae87a978be8`

I am using the results of the `get-retentioncompliancepolicy` (`74542cbb-45d5-44c2-bf26-9ae87a978be8`) to try to match it with the `get-mailbox inplaceholds` (`mbx74542cbb45d544c2bf269ae87a978be8:2`) and will be using this to compare multiple mailboxes.

Comment: Is the string always in that format? eg. `mbx<PolicyGUID>:<SomeDigit>`?

Comment: Yes, will always be MBX<string>:2

Comment: How about `'mbx74542cbb45d544c2bf269ae87a978be8:2' -replace 'mbx|:2'`

Comment: `'mbx74542cbb45d544c2bf269ae87a978be8:2' -replace '(?:mbx)(\w{8})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{12})(?:\:\d)' , '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5'`

Comment: oh there's dashes

Comment: @KeithMiller Works for me! You should answer the question and perhaps elaborate a bit

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to make the strings look identical? Couldn't you simply do something like this:

```
$GetRetentionCompliancePolicyResult = '74542cbb-45d5-44c2-bf26-9ae87a978be8'
$GetMailboxResult = 'mbx74542cbb45d544c2bf269ae87a978be8:2'
$GetMailboxResult -like '*{0}*' -f ($GetRetentionCompliancePolicyResult -replace '-')
```

The last line will equal `True` if they match.

(This is just an example of how to compare the results obviously, if you need help on the actual script logic to accomplish this we'll need to see some actual code).

Answer (score -1):

```
-join ("mbx74542cbb45d544c2bf269ae87a978be8:2")[3..99]
```

Comment: It's short and it works...